# Google Api Key doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps

I took an api key from Google for to use Google Maps for my android app. Yesterday it was working like charm but today i got an error when trying to load map. I opened logcat and it said

> Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

EDIT: My real issue is not because of that. That's because i got nullpointer exception error.

```
01-18 17:38:18.174: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1348): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 17:38:18.174: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.android.listxml.MyMap.onCreate(Map.java:69)
```

At this 69th line i have this code:

```
View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();
```

Comment: Is your phone internet enabled?

Comment: Do API keys expire after a certain period of time?

Comment: @Mathew im working on an emulator which has internet connection. I can get xml documentation such as latitude and longitude infos from internet.

Comment: @Andrew:I don't have an idea. When im trying to take new api key normally it gives me same key because of my md5 fingerprint.

Comment: @Semih: Your "error" will be there all of the time, as it has nothing to do with whatever you are experiencing. What other symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: @CommonsWare:At first I thought I could do a mistake in code and I undo my code and changed like same yestedar's code . But i get same error.

Comment: @Semih: I repeat: what are your symptoms? The error message you show above is perfectly normal.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Oh I got what u were trying to point. I am really sorry to take your time for my stupid mistake. When i deactivate zoomview from my application it's working back again. But i used zoomcontrol yesterday it was ok. But today it's turning nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the error you're getting, as the "Failed to find provider info..." is not related to this issue. Also, what changes were done recently that made it stopped working ?

Are you seening a stacktrace in logcat, or are you just seeing an empty map (no tiles being loaded) ?

You should double-check the following requirements for displaying maps in your Activity :

- A MapView component needs to be added
  to the layout that you're inflating in your Activity, and it should contain a valid
  Google Maps API key
- The Google Maps API key is linked to your SDK keystore. If you change the keystore, your API key will no longer be valid.
- The Activity that
  will be responsible for showing the
  map needs to extend from MapActivity
- The application manifest needs to be
  setup with the
  android.permission.INTERNET
  permission
- The application manifest
  needs to be setup with the
  com.google.android.maps library
- The application needs to run on an emulator with a target that includes the Google APIs

Some basic info is available in the [android sdk docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

The nullpointer exception can only be caused by the fact that mapView is null.
Assuming your code contains something like this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
```

Double check that the layout you're inflating (main.xml in this case), contains a MapView component with id mapview1, like the snippet below :

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:apiKey="your api key here" />
```

Comment: Yes my xml is exactly same. That's really weird. I created a new emulator and its working fine on it right now.